# How to use CRUD controller Index (list table) in other controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to make the list of table who have relation only, example:

Table:

- Order
- Process

In ProcessCrudController I want to replace the Process list view into Order list view that only have relation (order-process).

The solution I've tried:

- Create new function in OrderCrudController `return view($this->crud->getListView(), $this->data);`
- then, `addClause` using `$request->type` URL

The problem of that solution:

- Not showing the action row in table
- Easy to show all query if we try to remove URL

I really want to make the list view of Process that only already have relation to Order, or any suggestion/idea to make this happen?

*NB: I'm struggling at this problem I didn't found the solution, help me please*

EDIT (Adding Code):

OrderCrudController:

```
protected function setupListOperation()
{

    // This is the solution that I described before
    // $request = request();
    // $this->crud->addClause('where', 'user_id', '=', $request->type ?? 1);

    $this->crud->addColumns([
        [
            'name' => 'personal_name',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'type'  => 'text',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'notes',
            'label' => 'Catatan',
            'type'  => 'textarea',
        ],
        [
            'name'  => 'user_id',
            'label' => 'Dibuat oleh',
            'type'  => 'select',
            'entity' => 'user',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model' => 'App\User',
        ],
    ]);
}
```

ProcessCrudController:

```
protected function setupListOperation()
{
    CRUD::setFromDb();
    
    // This table should be listing Order's query and that only have a process (already created custom_create_view)
    // That's why i want to take Order's table and not making new custom_list_view
}
```

Comment: I think if you could provide a bit more of your code this would be very helpfull.

Comment: @ooorndtski here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to make a new view, you just modify the query result using addClause ....

in your ProcessCrudController in setupListOperation() add your clause:

```
 $this->crud->addClause('has','order');
```

assuming that the relation name in Process model that point to Process is "order"

Comment: I want to show OrderList in ProcessCrudController that only have a process, not showing the ProcessList